# how to compile in vc++ without .dsw workspace file?

Tags: visual-c++

I downloaded a source code from codeproject.com

In the zip file only .cpp files and .hpp files were present but no .dsw (vc++ work space) file.

how to compile the files in vc++.

source code link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13852/BasicExcel-A-Class-to-Read-and-Write-to-Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, vc++ requires a dsw. That said, you can easily create one by creating a project + workspace and add import all the files into the project.

Unless the code requires special compile options (unlikely if it comes without a project file), this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile in VisualC++ `cl.exe` is executed in order to compile a s program.
So a way to compile that does not require dsw file might be running compilation in command line. This is an example for a source file main.cpp:

```
call vsvars32.bat &&  cl /MD /Od /EHsc /GR /Zi  /Oy- main.cpp
```

On my computer the full path to `vsvars32.bat` is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

dsw is an ancient format, and is replaced by .sln and .vcxproj files.  What I would suggest would be File -> New -> Project from existing code, browse to the directory with the cpp/hpp files and let Visual Studio create the project with default compiler switches - so you won't have to run cl.exe from the command line as suggested here.

That being said, the chances of circa-2006 c++ code to work on IDEs 4 versions later are small.  You will almost certainly have to understand and fix the code - or find a more recent one that does what you need.

Comment: I am getting the folowing error: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup D:\User\Antony\Workspace\testexcel\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) testexcel

Comment: Is it supposed to be a console app by any chance? If so, change it's subsystem to Console: project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> System -> Subsystem = Console.

Comment: Solved, It was a console application. Thanks.